# Online Share Point can be used with office 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can I use SharePoint online having Office 2013 in my pc? We are a company of 5 people and I am looking to buy the SharePoint online plan 1. Is that a good ideia? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Office 2013 works very well with SharePoint Online

Comment: Can I used Share Point Online 2013 version?

Comment: Huh I do not understand?